# Designing a winform application / avoid modal model

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have to maintain a winform application.

It consists of a succession of modal window. (for example : on some screens, I can have 5 modal screen and there are a lot of problems).

I would like to migrate from the modal window to another model but I don't want to use the MDI style (it will take too long).

My feeling would be to create a class (all form will inherits from this form). In the constructeur we would provide in the parameter the parent form and it would handle, hide / show. This basic construction should work, but I have to handle the close event of the form.

Does someone have a solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. You want to have the interface continue to behave modally, but without using ShowDialog? Or do you want to have non-modal dialogs which auto-hide on loss of focus. Or something else?

Comment: I'd like to stop using showdialog. My idea would be to remove the modal dialog. A small exemple will be better, I have 2 form, the main which is opened first. I want to show a new dialog, for example the list of the users. So I want to auto hide the main dialog when I will show the list of the user. When I close the list of the user, I'll show again the main form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could the child and parent forms be the same size? If so, rather than hiding/showing forms, I'd consider having several panels on top of each other, and using BringToFront to show whichever one is current. This seems cleaner and less painful to me than messing around with magic windows...

If you *do* go with magic windows, you'll want to remember to play with the 'show in taskbar' property.

(Having windows which open and close 'automatically' and are different sizes could be pretty annoying for the user too)

Comment: @Philippe, you're welcome. By the way, have you seen [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage)?

Comment: Another alternative would be to have a 'popout'-style interface (like you sometimes see with a 'More...' button)

Answer (score 2):

The other paradigms that spring to mind for this sort of UI are a Wizard, which guides you from one form to the next, or a UI where each of your currently modal forms are displayed as expandable regions of a single UI.

Comment: I don't want to the use a wizard paradigm. It isn't a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about you hold a reference somewhere to all the forms designated as children. Whenever your parent window starts closing, close the children first. Something along those lines.